# Prisma @updatedAt generates value at creation?

Tags: node.js, prisma

I tried to follow the prisma getting started here [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/relational-databases/using-prisma-migrate-typescript-postgres).

When I first create a user using the prisma client, the updatedAt field already has a value. I assumed it should only generate a value upon update.

Here is the main code

```
async function main() {
  // ... you will write your Prisma Client queries here

  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email: "test@gmail1.com",
      name: "test",
    },
  });

  const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
  console.log(users);
}
```

Here is the result when I run the index.ts file

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'test@gmail.com',
    name: 'test',
    createdAt: 2022-02-11T03:49:00.090Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-02-11T03:49:00.090Z
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default Prisma generates `@updatedAt` value when you create entities.

You can override it on your app side by passing `null` there (and of course then you need to make field nullable too):

```
  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email: "test@gmail1.com",
      name: "test",
      // Just pass null here
      updatedAt: null
    },
  });
```